# Subtitle in the wrong position and legend not visible

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, subtitle

I have five lists which I intend to plot in two separate subplots. In subplot 1 I want list 1, 2, 3 and 4; in subplot 2 I want list 4 and 5. These are the lists and the `event_index` used to set the `x label`.

```
event_index=['event 1','event 2','event 3','event 4','event 5','event 6','event 7','event 8','event 9','event 10']
list1 = [0.7,0.8,0.8,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.9,1.0,0.9]
list2 = [0.2,0.3,0.1,0.0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.1]
list3 = [0.4,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.4]
list4 = [78,87,77,65,89,98,74,94,85,73]
list5 = [16,44,14,55,34,36,76,54,43,32]
```

To produce the two subplots I use the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure() #Creates a new figure
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211) #First subplot: list 1,2,3, and 4
ax2 = ax1.twinx() #Creates a twin y-axis for plotting the values of list 4
line1 = ax1.plot(list1,'bo-',label='list1') #Plotting list1
line2 = ax1.plot(list2,'go-',label='list2') #Plotting list2
line3 = ax1.plot(list3,'ro-',label='list3') #Plotting list3
line4 = ax2.plot(list4,'yo-',label='list4') #Plotting list4
ax1.set_ylim(0,1)
ax1.set_xlim(1, len(event_index)+1)
ax1.set_ylabel('Some values',fontsize=12)
ax2.set_ylabel('% values',fontsize=12)
ax2.set_ylim(0,100)
ax2.set_xlim(1, len(event_index)+1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(212) #Second subplot: list 4 and 5
ax3.set_xlim(1, len(event_index)+1)
ax3.set_ylabel('% values',fontsize=12)
#Plotting Footprint % and Critical Cells %
ax3.plot(list4,'yo-',label='list4')
line5 = ax3.plot(list5,'mo-',label='list5')
#Assigning labels
lines = line1+line2+line3+line4+line5
labels = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
ax3.legend(lines, labels, loc=(0,-0.4), ncol=5) #The legend location. All five series are in the same legend.
ax3.set_xlabel('events')
title_string=('Some trends')
subtitle_string=('Upper panel: list 1, 2, 3, and 4 | Lower panel: list 4 and 5')
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=8)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

What I get is this:
[image]

**A few problems:**

1. The subtitle is not above the first subplot but above the second
2. I cannot see/read the legend, which I want to be centered, but below the `x labels` of subplot 2
3. All my lists have `len=10`, but only `9` values are plotted
4. Possibly, I want to get rid of the `y-axis` ticks in the second subplot
5. I would like the chart title, **Some trends**, not to be "glued" to the first subplot

How could I improve my chart? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it too much? They all relate to the same topic, which is how to properly display a 2-subplot chart. Also, some of the separate questions could be labeled as `duplicate`, and future readers might incur in the same problem...

Comment: I showed you in your last question how to make room for the legend at the bottom. You need to `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)` (you might need to adjust the 0.3)

Comment: you only have 9 points because you are cutting out the first by setting `xlim` to `(1,len(list)+1)`, since python indexes from 0, not 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Plot the subtitle using `ax1.set_title`, not `plt.title` (as that will plot a title on the last active subplot)
2. I showed you in your last question how to make room for the legend at the bottom. You need to fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3) (you might need to adjust the 0.3)
3. you only have 9 points because you are cutting out the first by setting xlim to (1,len(list)+1), since python indexes from 0, not 1. Instead, create a list to plot as your x values:

   ```
   x = range(1,len(list1)+1)
   ax1.plot(x, list1)
   ```
4. Use `ax3.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')` to only plot the ticks on the left and turn them off on the right
5. You can move this increasing the `y` argument, e.g.

   ```
   plt.suptitle(title_string, y=1.05, fontsize=17)
   ```

Comment: Yes, sorry. Point 4 refers to the `y-axis` ticks on the lower subgraph. I will reword the question itself.

Comment: on both sides, or just the left?

Comment: Yes, sorry. On the right side, if possible. If not, no worries.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer #1: if I call `ax1.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=8)`, I get `TypeError: 'Text' object is not callable` pointing right to the line where `ax1.title()` is.

Comment: ah yes, that was meant to be `ax1.set_title`. Edited again

Comment: It works. I imagine I can move the subtitle wherever I want by setting `y=0.98`, for instance. The problem is that if I leave it this way, it gets "glued" to the main title, which has `y=1.00`. But if the main title has `y=1.05`, it goes out of view, so I cannot find a balance here...

Comment: Is there any way of "moving" everything down to have titles and charts more spaced out?

Comment: in the same way you make space at the bottom, you can make space at the top, e.g. `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85,bottom=0.2)`

Answer (score 3):

1. You can manually set the position of the suptitle as described here: http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.suptitle 
   Just use it like this with x and y being relative coordinates of your plot (from 0 to 1):

   ```
   suptitle("Here goes the title", x=0.5, y=0.95)
   ```
2. You can set the legend position with as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/5528308 Try this as suggested by user Joe Kington

   ```
   # Shrink current axis's height by 10% on the bottom
   box = ax.get_position()
   ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.1,
            box.width, box.height * 0.9])

   # Put a legend below current axis
   ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
         fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)
   ```
3. Your plots only show 9 values, because you x-axes start at 1 but Python's iteration starts at 0. Since you give no x values in your plot, Python plots from 0 to 9 but you limited the axes from 1 to 10. Do this:

   ```
   x_vals = np.linspace(1,10,10)
   line1 = ax1.plot(x_vals, list1,'bo-',label='list1')
   ```

   and repeat for the other plots.
4. What do you mean by grid? Usually grid refers to the gridlines, which you do not have. If you mean the ticks you can remove them with `ax2.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])`
5. Try using `plt.gcf().tight_layout()`. This will arrange your plot with proper whitespace everywhere in most cases.